# Can I render highcharts as I scroll down the page?

Tags: highcharts

I have a page with five widgets stacked vertically, and highcharts exist on the first, third, and fifth, so only one is ever visible at a time. Is there a way to animate the charts when they are scrolled down to, instead of only animating it on page load? I have read the documentation on chart.animation and plotOptions.series.animation but as an amateur programmer am not sure how to manipulate them to my needs. Thank you!

Comment: You will need [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport) or in [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Comment: Please provide a live demo of your charts (jsfiddle ideally) with your attempts included.